# SendGrid throwing InvalidApiRequestException in sending email

Tags: c#, email, asp.net-core, sendgrid

SendGrid is throwing an `InvalidApiRequestException` when sending an email.

I am using this code:

```
public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
{
    // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
    var myMessage = new SendGrid.SendGridMessage();
    myMessage.AddTo(email);
    myMessage.From = new MailAddress("varshney@shobhit.com", "Shobhit", System.Text.Encoding.Default);
    myMessage.Subject = subject;
    myMessage.Text = message;
    myMessage.Html = message;
    var credentials = new NetworkCredential(
        Options.SendGridUser,
        Options.SendGridKey);
    // Create a Web transport for sending email.
    var transportWeb = new SendGrid.Web(credentials);
    // Send the email.
    if (transportWeb != null)
    {
        return transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
    }
    else
    {
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Stack Trace is:

```
InvalidApiRequestException: Bad Request Check `Errors` for a list of errors returned by the API.
SendGrid.ErrorChecker.CheckForErrors(HttpResponseMessage response, Stream stream)
SendGrid.ErrorChecker.<CheckForErrorsAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
SendGrid.Web.<DeliverAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
MessageBoard.Controllers.AccountController.<Register>d__9.MoveNext() in AccountController.cs
                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(model.Email, "Confirm your account",
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionExecutor.<CastToObject>d__8`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.<InvokeActionFilterAsync>d__53.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__44.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Infrastructure.MvcRouteHandler.<RouteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.Template.TemplateRoute.<RouteAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.RouteCollection.<RouteAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler.IISPlatformHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Comment: When you call SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message) what values are you using for email, subject, and message?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using SendGrid C# Library version 6.3.x or later. There was a bug in the previous library version.

Answer (score 0):

For your credentials, are you using your Sendgrid username and password? Or your API key? From your variable names it appears you are passing your API key. Try passing your password instead:

Options.SendGridUser
Options.SendGridPassword

Comment: I am using my sendgrid userid nd password.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue. In my case root cause was some German characters in email address. To log exact error try adding below try/catch block.

```
            try
            {
                // Create a Web transport for sending email.
                var transportWeb = new SendGrid.Web(credentials);
                // Send the email.
                if (transportWeb != null)
                {
                    return transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
                }
            }
            catch (InvalidApiRequestException exception)
            {
                if (exception.Errors != null)
                {
                    foreach (var error in exception.Errors)
                    {
                        // Log error
                    }
                } 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy to consume the sendgrid API without any packages (Except newtonsoft json).
In my sample, I use templates; You can use content with outcommenting the content field

1) Create your Classes

```
public class MailObject
    {
        public ICollection<MailPersonalizations> personalizations { get; set; }
        public Email from { get; set; }
        public string template_id { get; set; }
        //public ICollection<MailContent> content { get; set; }
    }

public class MailPersonalizations
    {
        public ICollection<Email> to { get; set; }
        public string subject { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> substitutions { get; set; }
    }

public class MailContent
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

public class Email
    {
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

2) Create your MailObject and send it with HttpClient

```
public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message, string url = "", string buttonText = "")
        {
            //Create a mail object
            var mailObject = new MailObject {
                personalizations = new List<MailPersonalizations>(),
                from = new Email { email = "no-reply@passion4it.be", name = "No-Reply Passion4IT" },
                template_id = "cc84680c-a569-428b-ab26-9618584bc9ae"
            };

            //create the mail personalization
            var personalization = new MailPersonalizations();
            personalization.to = new List<Email>();
            personalization.to.Add(new Email { email = email});
            personalization.subject = subject;
            //Substitutions
            personalization.substitutions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            personalization.substitutions.Add("-url-", url);
            personalization.substitutions.Add("-title-", subject);
            personalization.substitutions.Add("-custtext-", message);
            personalization.substitutions.Add("-buttonText-", buttonText);

            mailObject.personalizations.Add(personalization); //Adding to the mail object

            //SEND EMAIL USING SENDGRID API
            using(var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var jsonMail = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mailObject);//convert object

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear(); //Clear headers
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); //Add Accept type
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "YOUR API KEY"); //Add Authorization

                var response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send", new StringContent(jsonMail, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")); //Send the mail
            }

            return; //Closed
        }
```