# SendGrid throwing InvalidApiRequestException

Tags: c#, email, sendgrid

Sendgrid is sending the Invalid Api Request exception.

I am using the following code:

```
try
{
    SendGridMessage message = new SendGridMessage();
    message.From = new MailAddress("test@gmail.com", "Poonam");
    message.AddTo("ppändey@test.com");

    message.Subject = "Test Email Subject";
    message.Subject.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKD);
    message.Html = "<b>Test Email</b>";
    message.EnableTemplateEngine(SendGridTemplateId);

    await DeliverMessage(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
catch (InvalidApiRequestException e)
{
    throw;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

The exact error that i am getting is "**InvalidApiRequestException: Invalid email address ppändey@test.com**"

When i try to change the email id from "ppändey@test.com" to "ppandey@test.com" it works fine (i.e. replacing the ä with a).

This issue is somewhat similar to what define in [SendGrid throwing InvalidApiRequestException in sending email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842671/sendgrid-throwing-invalidapirequestexception-in-sending-email)

But i am unable to find the solution. Can anyone please suggest what can be the solution for this.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the email address you provided `ppändey@test.com` contains unicode characters which are still not supported as valid email id characters by Sendgrid , but it's scheduled to be released in upcoming releases.